# how can SELECT a row of TABLE and then INSERT to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

IN SQL SERVER 2014.

Query of SQL

I want create table FCD_Assembly with two tables of FCD and Assembly .

my table like this :

======================||  Assembly TABLE  ||=========================

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID_Assembly | Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 | Col_5 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1200        | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 1201        | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
| 1202        | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 1203        | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 1204        | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
```

======================||  FCD TABLE  ||=========================

```
+--------+--------+------+
| ID_FCD | Tittle | type |
+--------+--------+------+
| 1      | Col_1  | F    |
| 2      | Col_2  | F    |
| 3      | Col_3  | F    |
| 4      | Col_4  | C    |
| 5      | Col_5  | D    |
```

======================||  FCD_Assembly TABLE  ||=========================

```
+-------------+-------------+
| ID_FCD      | ID_Assembly |
+-------------+-------------+
| 3           | 1200        |
| 1           | 1201        |
| 5           | 1201        |
| 2           | 1202        |
| 4           | 1203        |
| 2           | 1204        |
| 5           | 1204        |
```

I want create table FCD_Assembly

thank you for your help :)

Comment: Which programming environment?

Comment: @jarlh SQL programming language

Comment: SQL doesn't really have arrays, as such. Can you be clearer about your intent? What do you actually want to do with the data, beyond copying it into some array-like structure?

Comment: @ADyson Oh, I did't know that
So I should say , in this TABLE I have some key (in each of 6 column) and I need to read one by one and then write in another table :(

Comment: @ADyson Maybe I should edit my question and explain more

Comment: you need to insert the value from each column into a different table? e.g. from Col_1 into a row in Table_1, from Col_2 into a row in Table_2 etc. Like that?  Or all into different columns in the same table? Also, insert a new row, or update the value(s) in an existing row? Perhaps you could give us an example, to be clearer. It would be great if you could edit the question, yes - thankyou.

Comment: @ADyson ok ok , so let me explain more and edit my question . thank you pal

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: `copy to array` - Where is this array going to live? Is it your intention e.g. to create a C# array variable? SQL Server **does not have arrays**, it only has Tables. Yet all you mention is sql.

Comment: @ADyson 
my edit is finish
please read again

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it's still not particularly clear. What is the relationship between these tables? Is this existing data, or the data you want to create? Where does the value for `type` come from? And you need to remove the reference to arrays as well.

Comment: @ADyson  
 Assembly TABLE is Static Table
 . FCD_Assembly TABLE is the interface between the two tables Assembly  and FCD

Comment: and what about FCD?

Comment: @ADyson 
Do you know actually I want create table FCD_Assembly with two tables of FCD and Assembly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `unpivot` for `Assembly` table let the column name to row value, then do `join` with `FCD` table.

I would use `CROSS APPLY` to do `unpivot`.

```
SELECT f.ID_Assembly,t1.id 
FROM (
    select v.* from Assembly CROSS APPLY 
    (
        VALUES 
        (ID_Assembly,Col_1,'Col_1'),
        (ID_Assembly,Col_2,'Col_2'),
        (ID_Assembly,Col_3,'Col_3'),
        (ID_Assembly,Col_4,'Col_4'),
        (ID_Assembly,Col_5,'Col_5')
    )  v (id,val,Title)
    WHERE v.val <> 0
)t1 JOIN FCD f on t1.Title = f.Tittle
```

[sqlifddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d87cade26a86cecf91f97c37ed3d24f5)

**Result**

```
ID_FCD  ID_Assembly
3       1200
1       1201
5       1201
2       1202
4       1203
2       1204
5       1204
```